# ASP.NET Treeview control failing to handle angle brackets in data

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, treeview

I have some data which contains angle brackets in some of the fields.

Even if properly escaped as `&lt:` or `&gt;` (or even the hex codes), in Visual Studio 2005 ASP.Net, the field data is being truncated at the first angle bracket. If I replace the data with curly braces, it displayes fine.

Example Data (unescaped):

`<ITReview><row TopNode="REQ 123456 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>"/><row TopNode="REQ 456789 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>"/></ITReview><ITReview><row TopNode="REQ 123456 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>"/><row TopNode="REQ 456789 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>"/></ITReview>`

Example Data (escaped):

```
<ITReview>
<row TopNode="REQ 123456&#x09;TT Description&#x09;&lt;Date sent to app dev&gt;&#x09;&lt;Priority&gt;&#x09;&lt;SubTask Status&gt;"/>
<row TopNode="REQ 456789&#x09;TT Description&#x09;&lt;Date sent to app dev&gt;&#x09;&lt;Priority&gt;&#x09;&lt;SubTask Status&gt;"/>
</ITReview>
```

Not doing anything tricky, binding the TreeView to an XMLDataSource with the file name set, and specifying the binding as DataMember=row and TextField=TopNode.

I didn't find anything online, but of course searching for "angle bracket" just increases the number of results, not decreases them.

Anyone see anything like this? Know of a workaround or solution? ASP.Net v2.0.50727.

Update: example of the CDATA I used, as suggested. Didn't work.

`<ITReview> 
<TopNode> 
<MainData>
<![CDATA[REQ 123456 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>]]>
</MainData>
</TopNode>
<TopNode>
<MainData>
<![CDATA[REQ 456789 TT Description <Date sent to app dev> <Priority> <SubTask Status>]]>
</MainData>
</TopNode>
</ITReview>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I double encode the angle brackets, it appears to work, at least how I think you're looking for. So `&amp;lt;` instead of `<`

I poked around looking for the cause of this thinking there might be a setting you could change. It looks like it's coming from the Value property of the XmlAttribute class, but I don't see a way to turn it off.

Comment: By George, it works! Thanks! Looks like a slightly obscure parser issue. I may report it to MS, just for information.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it out within the context of an HTMLEncode()

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the source XML, such that instead of having your data in the TopNode="" attribute, you have `<row><TopNode><![CDATA[long string]]></TopNode></row>`?